# Gradle unable to write sysout to file - java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am trying to put output of a command to some file. Before writing the file i want to delete the file and than do write operation. Here is my gradle script

```
group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

task deletefiles(type: Delete){
    delete "$projectDir/somefile.txt"
}

task writefile(type: Exec, dependsOn: deletefiles){
    commandLine 'echo', "Hello World"
    standardOutput = new FileOutputStream("$projectDir/somefile.txt")
}
```

But when i run writefile tasks , I get below error

```
Execution failed for task ':deletefiles'.
> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file 'D:\workspace\code\repo\sample-gradle-mono\somefile.txt'
```

Any idea what's wrong?

One thing i guess is that gradle is somehow acquiring lock on file before **deletefiles** tasks could start. If that is the case, How can we achieve this?

Edit 1:
Enviroment info -

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.4 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.4+11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Comment: what version of Gradle are you using? which OS?

Comment: what happens if you run `deletefiles` alone?

Comment: @MichaelEaster Edited question with details you needed.

Comment: @injecteer Same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem that in your gradle the following line executed at project configuration phase

```
standardOutput = new FileOutputStream("$projectDir/somefile.txt")
```

it means that stream is created and file locked even before any gradle task was started..

try this groovy configuration to see the issue:

```
class MyStream extends FileOutputStream{
    MyStream(String f){ 
        super(f)
        println "write $f stream created" 
    }
}

task deletefiles(type: Delete){
    println "delete init"
    doFirst{
        println "delete doFirst" //triggered just before deletion
    }
    delete "out.txt"
}

task writefile(type: Exec, dependsOn: deletefiles){
    println "write init"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/C', 'echo', "Hello World"
    standardOutput = new MyStream("out.txt")
}
```

in output you can see that stream is created before tasks execution:

```
cmd> gradle writeFile

> Configure project :
delete init
write init
write out.txt stream created

> Task :deletefiles FAILED
delete doFirst

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deletefiles'.
> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file 'out.txt'
```

---

**To fix it** - define the `standardOutput` just before the "Exec" task is executed:

```
class MyStream extends FileOutputStream{
    MyStream(String f){ 
        super(f)
        println "write $f stream created" 
    }
}

task deletefiles(type: Delete){
    println "delete init"
    doFirst{
        println "delete doFirst"
    }
    delete "out.txt"
}

task writefile(type: Exec, dependsOn: deletefiles){
    println "write init"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/C', 'echo', "Hello World"
    doFirst{
        println "write doFirst"
        standardOutput = new MyStream("out.txt")
    }
    doLast{
        println "write doLast"
    }
}
```

output:

```
cmd>gradle writeFile

> Configure project :
delete init
write init

> Task :deletefiles
delete doFirst

> Task :writefile
write doFirst
write out.txt stream created
write doLast

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

---

to add **some clarity**:

for example the this task definition

```
task writefile(type: Exec, dependsOn: deletefiles){
    println "write init"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/C', 'echo', "Hello World"
    doFirst{
        println "write doFirst"
        standardOutput = new MyStream("out.txt")
    }
    doLast{
        println "write doLast"
    }
}
```

you could replace with the following groovy code in your gradle:

```
def writefile = project.task( [type: Exec, dependsOn: deletefiles], 'writeFile' )

println "write init"
writefile.setCommandLine( ['cmd', '/C', 'echo', "Hello World"] )

writefile.getActions().add( 0, {
    //those commands will be executed later when task `writefile` decided to be executed by gradle
    println "write doFirst"
    writefile.standardOutput = new FileOutputStream("out.txt")
} as Action)

writefile.getActions().add( {
    //those commands will be executed later when task `writefile` decided to be executed by gradle
    println "write doLast" 
} as Action)
```

---

links to official documentation that could explain this behavior:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:settings_file

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

Comment: Thanks for the details @daggett . This really helped. In my case I created streams in doFirst block and had processed them in exec{} closure.

Comment: Hey @daggett, It would be really helpful If you could share any documentation related to this behavior? Due to your explanation, I understand what is happening but I don't understand why. It is a bit counter-intuitive that the task function is executed rather than be processed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added two links to official documentation. I would compare the code between `task {...}` to constructor of task where you specifying for gradle "how to create an instance of the task", and with doLast/doFirst you could specify what to do during task execution ...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that something is holding the file open.  Sometimes if IO streams are not properly closed this can happen. Gradle docs say that exec task closes the output stream after the process terminates, so that shouldn't be the problem.
It could be a known issue with deleting on Windows.  E.g.:
https://carlrice.io/blog/gradle-clean-cant-delete-file-on-windows

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9813 (but that one is about folders)

https://www.eknori.de/2020-09-18/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-appclean-unable-to-delete-file/

I would run the build with --debug to capture more details of the exception.

Are you running with the Gradle daemon?  Try without it.  Since it is a persistent process, maybe for some reason it has a file handle open to that file.

Comment: While this could be one of the reasons, But in my case, problem was creation of IO streams in the configuration phase.